# SAPI how to identify multiple properties

Tags: c++, sapi

I am trying to write code that will identify multiple properties in a phrase. Phrases already can be identified when spoken; however, I need it to know where to go; in this case, a specific case = CASE PONY:. I am having few issues with it crashing once it reaches the case. It says its a bad pointer and I'm not sure how to fix that. This is what I have done and tried so far. Any help will be awesome!

C++ code snippet

```
const SPPHRASEPROEPRTY* FindPropertyCore(Const SPPHRASEPROEPRTY* pProp, LPCWSTR propName) {
 while (pProp != NULL) {
    if (wcscmp(propName, pProp->pszName)==0) {
        return pProp ;
    }

    if (pProp->pFirstChild != NULL) {
        const SPPHRASEPROEPRTY* pChild = FindProperty(pProp->pFirstChild, propName) ;
        if (pChild) {
            return pChild ;
        }
    }
    pProp = pProp->pNextSibling ;
 }
 return pProp ;
}

const SPPHRASEPROEPRTY* FindProperty(const SPPHRASE* pPhrase, LPCWSTR propName) {
return FindPropertyCore(pPhrase->pProperties, propName)
}

SPPHRASE* pPhrase = NULL ;

HRESULT OnRecognition(ISpRecoResult* pRecoResult) {
SPPHRASE* pPhrase (NULL) ;
HRESULT hr = pRecoResult->GetPhrase(&pPhrase) ;
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    const SPPHRASEPROEPRTY* pProperty = FindProperty(pPhrase, L"/*blank for now, but a word(s) would go in here*/");
    if (pProperty != NULL) {
        //stuff
    }
    ::CoTaskMemFree(pPhrase) ;
}
return hr ;
}

std::wstring processPhrase(ISpPhrase *pPhrase, HWND hWnd) {
SPPHRASE *pElements ;
std::wstring str ;
}    
     if (SUCCEEDED(pPhrase->GetPhrase(&pElements)))
{        
    SPPHRASE phrase = *pElements ; 
    WCHAR *pText ; 
    if (SUCCEEDED(pPhrase->GetText(SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, TRUE, &pText, NULL))) {
        str = pText ; 

    }    

   switch ( pElements->Rule.ulId) {
   case CAT_PONIES:
      HRESULT hr = pRecoResult->GetPhrase(&pPhrase) ;
      if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
         const SPPHRASEPROEPRTY* pProperty = FindProperty(pPhrase, L"");
         if (pProperty != NULL) {
                 //stuff
      }
   break ;
    ::CoTaskMemFree(pPhrase) ;
}
return hr ;
   }
}
```

XML code snippet

```
<RULE NAME="PONIES" ID="CAT_PONIES" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE">
    <L>
        <P>
            <O>
                <L>
                    <P PROPID="FEMALE" VALSTR="female">female</P>
                    <P PROPID="MALE" VALSTR="male">male</P>
                </L>
            </O>
            <RULEREF NAME="BROWN_BLACK"/>
            <P>pony</P>
            <O>
                <L>
                    <RULEREF NAME="STABLED"/>
                </L>
            </O>
        </P>
    </L>
</RULE>
<RULE NAME="BROWN_BLACK" ID="R_BROWN_BLACK">
    <L>
        <P PROPID="BROWN" VALSTR="brown">brown</P>
        <P PROPID="BLACK" VALSTR="black">black</P>
    </L>
```

```
<RULE NAME="STABLED" ID="R_STABLED">
    <L>
        <P PROPID="STABLED" VALSTR="stabled">stabled</P>
        <P PROPID="NOT_STABLED" VALSTR="not stabled">not stabled</P>
    </L>
</RULE>`
```

Here are the phrases: 
"Female brown pony is stabled"
"Female black pony is stabled"
"Female brown pony is not stabled"
"Female black pony is not stabled"
"Male brown pony is stabled"
"Male black pony is stabled"
"Male brown pony is not stabled"
"Male black pony is not stabled"

Comment: Are all your pointer initialized (and not `nullptr`) ?

Comment: @Jarod42 - I did that on a previous version, and it gave me the same error message in result of crashing.

`const SPPHRASEPROPERTY *pProp = NULL ;  const SPPHRASERULE *pRule = NULL ;`  
`if ( pRule != NULL ) {
if ( phrase.pProperties->pFirstChild->pszValue != NULL && wcscmp ( L"female", phrase.pProperties->pFirstChild->pszValue ) != NULL ) {
      //do something
     
     if ( wcscmp ( L"brown", phrase.pProperties->pFirstChild->pNextSibling->pszName ) == 0 ) {
      //do something
     }
     else if ( 0 == wcscmp ( L"black", phrase.pProperties->pszName )) {
      //do something
     }`

Comment: Comment are not good for all non inline code. You may edit your question with relevant code if needed. provided code does nothing btw as you initialize with `nullptr`, but do action if not `nullptr`...

Comment: @Jarod42 - So just to clarify and please correct if I am wrong, the initialization of a pointer and for it actually do the action I want, would have to be both  `!=nullptr` ?

Comment: Yes, not sure if you need pointer neither in your case.

Comment: I suspect the relevant code you need to show is the code that *retrieves* the properties, not the grammar building code.   If you edit your question to show the property retrieval code, it would help immensely.

Comment: The code you've added in your comment doesn't initialize pProp or pRule to be anything other than NULL.   In particular, you seem to be missing a call to `ISpRecoResult::GetPhrase`.

Comment: @Eric Brown - Yes, I am trying to retrieve the properties. I was not sure how to ask for it. But I do not need to build the grammar. Do you have an example for me to look at? I am having trouble understanding the retrieval portion

Answer (score 0):

I have a pair of (C++) functions that I've used in just about every SAPI recognition project that I've ever used.

```
const SPPHRASEPROPERTY* FindProperty(const SPPHRASE* pPhrase, LPCWSTR propName) const
{
    return FindPropertyCore(pPhrase->pProperties, propName);
}

const SPPHRASEPROPERTY* FindPropertyCore(const SPPHRASEPROPERTY* pProp, LPCWSTR propName) const
{
    while (pProp != NULL)
    {
        if (wcscmp(propName, pProp->pszName) == 0)
        {
            return pProp;
        }
        if (pProp->pFirstChild != NULL)
        {
            const SPPHRASEPROPERTY* pChild = FindPropertyCore(pProp->pFirstChild, propName);
            if (pChild)
            {
                return pChild;
            }
        }
        pProp = pProp->pNextSibling;
    }
    return pProp;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
HRESULT OnRecognition(ISpRecoResult* pRecoResult)
{
    SPPHRASE* pPhrase(NULL);
    HRESULT hr = pRecoResult->GetPhrase(&pPhrase);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        const SPPHRASEPROPERTY* pProperty = FindProperty(pPhrase, "FEMALE");
        if (pProperty != NULL)
        {
            // stuff
        }
        ::CoTaskMemFree(pPhrase);
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Lastly, your grammar is badly structured.   You want to have the same property with different values.   Something like this:

```
<RULE NAME="PONIES" ID="CAT_PONIES" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE">
    <L>
        <P>
            <O>
                <L>
                    <P PROPNAME="GENDER" VALSTR="female">female</P>
                    <P PROPNAME="GENDER" VALSTR="male">male</P>
                </L>
            </O>
            <RULEREF NAME="BROWN_BLACK"/>
            <P>pony</P>
            <O>
                <L>
                    <RULEREF NAME="STABLED"/>
                </L>
            </O>
        </P>
    </L>
</RULE>
<RULE NAME="BROWN_BLACK" ID="R_BROWN_BLACK">
    <L>
        <P PROPNAME="COLOR" VALSTR="brown">brown</P>
        <P PROPNAME="COLOR" VALSTR="black">black</P>
    </L>

<RULE NAME="STABLED" ID="R_STABLED">
    <L>
        <P PROPNAME="STABLED" VALSTR="stabled">stabled</P>
        <P PROPNAME="STABLED" VALSTR="not stabled">not stabled</P>
    </L>
</RULE>`
```

Now you can call `FindProperty(pPhrase, L"STABLED")` to see if the pony has been stabled; `FindProperty(pPhrase, L"COLOR")` to get the pony's color, or `FindProperty(pPhrase, L"GENDER")` to get the pony's gender.

Comment: I'm getting a couple errors from the code you've provided. On the first line, it says that "const SPPHRASEPROPERTY*" is incompatible with parameter of type "const SPPHRASE*. Also, "FindProperty" has an error messaging saying "local function definitions are illegal". I don't understand these errors or how to fix them. An explanation and solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try reversing the order of the functions, or add forward declarations.  Also, it appears that you've pasted the code into the middle of an existing function, hence the 'local function definitions are illegal' error.

Comment: Okay, I understand what I did wrong from those errors, thank you. But, what if I have 2 categories: CAT_PONIES and CAT_COWS? Would I need to include the second snippet of your code in each case however many times / phrases? 

I have edited my code. Kindly, please take a look.

For example, if these phrases were choices to be said:
Female brown pony is stabled
Female black pony is stabled
Female brown pony is not stabled
Female black pony is not stabled

Comment: You would call FindProperty once for each property that you want to retrieve.  In your code snippet above, the OnRecognition method is redundant.  Looking at your grammar example, it looks like you're using PROPID instead of PROPNAME; that's perfectly valid, but it does mean that the properties will come back as numbers, not strings.  I'd change the grammar to use PROPNAME instead.

Comment: Also added changes to the grammar to use a consistent set of property names.